# How do I loop through the results of a SELECT statement

Tags: sql

How do I loop through the results of a SELECT statement
and by each value returned I will update a column in same table?

I have a table contains 3 columns:

- cases_id
- status
- isalreadysigned

I want to get all cases id with status signed. Then by for loop on returned values update the value on the column isalradysigned to true for the records having the same caseid but status not signed .

Comment: In SQL you're supposed to think in _sets_, instead of _procedural_ programming. What you're looking for is easily achieved by using a single `UPDATE` statement, without using any loop construct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not the loop but a kind of UPDATE/SELECT combination. Should look like:

```
UPDATE table
SET isalreadysigned = 1 
WHERE status <> 'signed'
 AND cases_id IN (
   SELECT cases_id 
   FROM table
   WHERE status = 'signed')
```